# PHPMailer "$mail->MsgHTML($msg)" issue with "$msg"

Tags: php, ajax, forms, phpmailer, mailer

I'm asking here because I did not got an answer from OVH (my hosting).
Here is the problem : 
If I replace $mail->MsgHTML($msg) with $mail->MsgHTML($_POST['message']), I receive the mail instantly with headers, name, email, subject and the message.
But when I put $msg instead, I receive no mail.

```
$msg='Name:'.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:'.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
IP:'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />

Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';
```

entire PHP (from FancyAJAXForm):

```
<?php
/* config start */

$emailAddress = 'my mail address';

/* config end */

require "class.phpmailer.php";

foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
$_POST[$k]=stripslashes($_POST[$k]);

$_POST[$k]=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$k]));
}


$msg='Name:'.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:'.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
IP:'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />

Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "Contact Form: ".mb_strtolower($_POST['subject'])." from    ".$_POST['name']."";

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();

?>
```

Comment: can you post the output of `var_dump($msg)`

Comment: Did you check the return value of `Send()`? Did you check your spam folder? Did you look at the headers of the email that did go through (there should be some info about the path the email takes, some relay servers are more picky than others about what they pass through)?

Comment: @ilanco : the var_dump($msg) return : "Name:
Email:
Subject:
IP: **my ip

Message:

" DCoder: As I said, I receive mail when I replace MsgHTML($msg) by MsgHTML($_POST['message']);

Comment: my guess it's being stopped by a spam filter, try to send to an account on the local machine and see if you receive the message

Comment: An account on the local machine? Dunno how to do that... by the way I'm waiting an answer from OVH. Maybe it will take more time for this kind of mail to be processed by the server? Thanks for your answers, if someone has an idea or want to share a thought, he's welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I got the problem solved.

I've replace $mail->msgHTML($msg) with the body function :

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body='Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Sujet:  '.$_POST['subject'].'
<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

<br /><br /> 
Browser:  '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'<br />
IP:  '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br />
';

$mail->Send();
```

It works perfectly!
Thanks to all participants!

Comment: since you've got the solution, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick icon. this will help anyone else looking for a similar answer in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't exactly timely, but I found an alternative solution:

I had a similar problem, but I had some pages that worked and some that didn't.  I tried your solution, but it gave me the same results.

Then I looked at the html source of the emails from the working pages, and noticed that I had included the opening and closing html and body tags, and I hadn't included them in the non-working pages.  That's all it took, and $mail->msgHTML($msg) worked for me.

Hope this helps.