# phpmailer html mail content shows as blank

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

CODE

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'email';
$mail->Password   = 'pass';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->AddReplyTo("email", "name");
$mail->SetFrom("email", "name");
$mail->Subject = "subject";
$mail->AddAddress($emailaddress);
$ms = "<html><head>.... some html ....</html";
$mail->MsgHTML($ms);
$send = $mail->Send();
```

I don't know why, all emails are displayed as blank in outlook and few others mail clients, like the html doesn't render at all. Downloading the email and viewing the content, you can see all the html code though

Is anything wrong in my code? How you fix this compatibility issue?

This is the content of the email I'm sending
https://jsfiddle.net/dm6txye5/

Comment: maybe using `$mail->IsHTML(true);$mail->Body=$ms;` instead of `$mail->MsgHTML($ms);`? .. it could be an attempt before further investigation

Comment: @DiegoD I tried using those instead of MsgHTML but the mail is still showing as blank sadly

Comment: there is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373603/phpmailer-mail-msghtmlmsg-issue-with-msg that solved like that ... the other user and I also gave the same suggestion. I'm clueless at this point. There's the chance that you should use a valid html for your body (for example correctly closing the `</html>` tag that is invalid (`</html`) in your example. For reference https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/56

Comment: @DiegoD I added a link with the mail content, do you think the mail is invalid? but it doesnt explain why it only happen on certain mail browsers... https://jsfiddle.net/dm6txye5/

Comment: Why are there multiple external JavaScript resources embedded in your mail template? No mail client will execute client-side script.

Comment: the jsfiddle you shared has a line highlighted in red where the inline style of a p element contains non escaped single quotes on the font-family. Just for the sake of addressing the issue, did you try first to send a very simple html content before? so that you know it works and then you try to better correct your current content

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of email HTML rendering, where every client is quite different, and has its own set of idiosyncrasies, much as the web did in the 1990s! This means that you have to code your HTML for email extremely conservatively – for example it's quite likely that gmail will simply delete/ignore your style tag entirely. Outlook isn't much better.

Comment: I solved the issue by changing the HTML content, seems it was wrongfully formatted, the issue was with the content and not with phpmailer